# Exact meaning of "as we choose"

Tags: grammar

What is the meaning of "as we choose" at the end of this sentence?
Does it mean "while choosing bachelors" or "choosing all things we are going to legislate"?

> Of course, we could always legislate that bachelors are all those men
>   above the age of 25 who have never been married and who do not belong
>   to any religious order … and so on, **as we choose**.

Answer (score 2):

It means there are more possible definitions of *bachelor* (that's why they say `and so on`), and **they are free to choose the one they find the most appropriate**. *As we choose* means "the way we choose", "as we wish":

> We may live *as we choose* (the way we want to).
>
> The renowned economic philosopher Amartya Sen speaks of the right of people to "seek our identity *as we choose*" (seek it the way we like).
>
> We have the right to move through the world *as we choose* (as we please), free from harassment or violence.

Comment: Thanks! But what does the choose refer to? Choosing bachelors of choosing other definitions?

Comment: @AhmadLotfi choosing the right definition for "bachelor"